# postfix relay use zoho cannot send to other email

Tags: postfix

i was setting up my ubuntu server with postfix to use zoho smtp as a relay (send only).
the files i edited/created are:

```
main.cf
sasl_passwd
sasl_passwd.db
```

it works well when i test send email to my other zoho's account (works well: the email is received), but the email is not received when i test send it to gmail and yahoo. there's no error in log file.

is it normal esp. when we use zoho as smtp server?

Answer (score 0):

The choice of SMTP server shouldn't affect external connectivity. In addition to a misconfiguration, your IP might be in a blacklist, or might have been used by spammers before.

You can try sending email to a disposable e-mail address (e.g. http://mailinator.com) to quickly check if gmail and yahoo is blocking you. (Did you check the spam folder on those services?)

More thorough investigation can be done by either increasing the logging levels of the server software, or by using `tcpdump` or similar to capture network traffic and check the data exchange in SMTP connection.